# Plist to UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview, plist

I am trying to populate a `UITableView` with information from a `plist` file. I don't know where I am going wrong. Please check the images for my requirement and the code above to find where I am wrong

[image: enter first]
I need to populate above image in `UITableView` in such way that array `a, b, c` should come in the section field. Its coming right in below. But I am unable to populate data
please check where I am wrong.
.

[image: second]
    .

```
@synthesize mySections  //array
@synthesize myData    //dictionary    

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //LOADING THE PLIST FILE

    //Create a string representing the file path
    NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"yourFilename" ofType:@"plist"];

    //Load the file in a dictionnary
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];

    self.myData = dict;

    //SORTING THE DICTIONARY    
    NSArray *dicoArray = [[self.myData allKeys] sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
          return [((NSString *)firstObject) compare:((NSString *)secondObject) options: NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
    }];

    self.mySections = dicoArray;
}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    //Return the number of sections.
    return [self.mySections count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
    NSArray *dataInSection = [self.myData objectForKey:key];
    return [dataInSection count];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
}

-(NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return self.mySections;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...


    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];

    NSDictionary *Dic=self.myData;   
    NSArray *dataForSection = [self.myData objectForKey:Dic.allKeys];



    cell.textLabel.text = [dataForSection objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;    

}
```

some code of plist is:-

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>a</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Beta_Carot_(µg)</key>
        <string>0.06</string>
        <key>Cholestrl_(mg)</key>
        <string>215</string>
        <key>fdgdfg</key>
        <string>dfgdfg</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>b</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha_Carot_(µg)</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>gdfg</key>
        <string>fdgdfg</string>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>c</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>Alpha_Carot_(µg)</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>Ash_(g)</key>
        <string>0</string>
        <key>Beta_Caro</key>
        <string>193</string>
        <key>Choline_Tot_ (mg)</key>
        <string>22.3</string>
        <key>dgd</key>
        <string>dgdf</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get to count the number of elements in the right data structure when determining the number of rows in each section. So in `- tableView: numberOfRowsInSection:` you need to have

```
NSArray *dataInSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];
return [dataInSection count];
```

There is also a problem in `- tableView: cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. You create the correct key to get the data for your section in `*key` but then you instead use `Dic.allKeys` as a key to retrieve data from `self.myData`. So you are sending in a whole array as the key when you set `*dataForSection`.

So change these lines:

```
NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];

NSDictionary *Dic=self.myData;   
NSArray *dataForSection = [self.myData objectForKey:Dic.allKeys];

cell.textLabel.text = [dataForSection objectAtIndex:row];
```

To:

```
NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
NSDictionary *dataForSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];

cell.textLabel.text = [[dataForSection allKeys] objectAtIndex:row];
```

Comment: ya thats working,...but giving first array first value,second array's only value..third array's third value

Comment: means a->beta_carot_(ug), b->gmwt-Desc1 ..c-> beta_carot_(ug)

Comment: I'm a bit confused about your datastructure. Do you have an array with several dicts in each section or only one dict in each section array?

Comment: now error comes,for dataForSection.allkeys   -> property alleys not found of object nsarray

Comment: Sry, there was an error, `*dataForSection` should be a pointer to a dict not an array. Does this work?

Comment: my actual plist contains of thousands of arrays,and multiple key string with in,for 10-20 array it displays fine.but when I store more,table gets awful.does not show properly.I used the expanded section code http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/  but not helpful for this much code..what can i do now

Comment: search plist problem..help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985379/uisearchview-not-displaying-search-values

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not drilling far enough down your data hierarchy. In `numberOfRowsInSection:` you're getting the value for the key in the root level dictionary: Looks like this is always an `NSArray` with only a single item: A dictionary. You probably want something like

```
...
NSDictionary *dataInSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];
return [dataInSection count]; 
...
```

Comment: this helps..this gives me proper.number of rows.but data is not displaying.means problem in cellforRowatindexpath left

Comment: search plist problem..help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985379/uisearchview-not-displaying-search-values

Answer (score 0):

According to me you are doing some mistake in  table fetch data from plist 
plz try this
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
//LOADING THE PLIST FILE

//Create a string representing the file path
NSString *plistPath = [bundle pathForResource:@"yourFilename" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *listArray=[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"yourFilename" ofType:@"plist"]];

self.sections = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

}
```

Then set your data according to your need from `plist` data come as an array, then `dict` may be help this information you..