# UISearchView not displaying search values

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

In my `TableView` which Expands on the clicking on the sections.now I am using `Uisearchbar` to search the sections in the table...It gives me the `UIsearchbar` but Search cannot be taken...
I think problem is in the  `numberOfRowsInSection`.please check where I am getting wrong..
why searchbar is not working

[image: enter day]

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{


return [self.mySections count];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {
 NSInteger rows = 0;


if ([self tableView:tableView canCollapseSection:section] || (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) )
{
    if ([expandedSections containsIndex:section] )
    {

        NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
        NSArray *dataInSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];

        return [dataInSection count];


    }
    return 1;
} else{

     rows = [self.searchResults count];
    return rows;
}

    return 1;


}

 -(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection: (NSInteger)section {
NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];
return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", key];
}

- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText 
                         scope:(NSString*)scope
{
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate 
                                predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                searchText];

self.searchResults = [self.allItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
UISearchBar * searchBar = [controller searchBar];
[self filterContentForSearchText:searchString scope:[[searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:[searchBar selectedScopeButtonIndex]]];
return YES;
}

-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
UISearchBar * searchBar = [controller searchBar];
[self filterContentForSearchText:[searchBar text] scope:[[searchBar scopeButtonTitles] objectAtIndex:searchOption]];
return YES;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
}

// Configure the cell...



if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) {
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}else {

NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];



NSString *key = [self.mySections objectAtIndex:section];

NSDictionary *dataForSection = [[self.myData objectForKey:key] objectAtIndex:0];
NSArray *array=dataForSection.allKeys;

cell.textLabel.text = [[dataForSection allKeys] objectAtIndex:row];    
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[dataForSection valueForKey:[array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reloading your table after searching

```
- (void)filterContentForSearchText:(NSString*)searchText
                             scope:(NSString*)scope
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

self.mySections = [self.mySections filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
[myTableView reloadData];
}
```

**Edit**

Your are not setting detail text label

```
if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView]) 
{
    cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text=[dataForSection valueForKey:[self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

and after searching you are getting title now row because in your code

```
 rows = [self.searchResults count];
return rows;
```

its always returning zero value.  So just do it `return 1;`

And do other thing as your requirement,

And i will suggest you to not to use different different code for  before table search  and after searching.. Like `if ([tableView isEqual:self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView])`

just use same code for both..and make changes only in array and dictionary..

initially

```
tableAry = globalAry;
```

And after searching

```
tableAry = searchedAry;
```

Comment: table searches but it won't be in the sections.. i want only sections to be searched...

Comment: self.searchResults = [self.mySections filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];

Comment: ya i have already done that...problem is when i search some section of say`butter oil1 from figure...it will give me that..but i won't give the expanded key values of that butter oil...i think `cellforrowatindexpath` need changes

Comment: search result (
    "BUTTER OIL,ANHYDROUS",
    "BUTTER,WHIPPED,WITH SALT",
    "BUTTER,WITH SALT",
    "MILK,BUTTERMILK,DRIED",
    "SOUR DRSNG,NON-BUTTERFAT,CULTURED,FILLED CREAM-TYPE"
)

Comment: but man problem is they are searching from plist where sections are there and 1) if i search section its not creating sections..2) celfforrowatindexpath changes required]